# Read one cell from each sheet of an Excel workbook and compile into a list (pandas/python)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have an Excel workbook with a bunch of sheets that I want to pull the contents of cell B4 and put all of those cells into a list, not a dictionary. I'm also pulling information from other parts of each sheet but I don't think I can do both at the same time so my code looks like this:

```
sheets = pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name=None, index_col=None, usecols="D:G", skiprows=14, nrows=8)
cells = pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name=None, index_col=None, header=None, usecols="B", skiprows=5, nrows=0)
```

I then tried to convert cells into a dataframe (because each of the items in sheets is a dataframe):

```
cells2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(cells)
```

and I get this error:

```
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still didn't get the whole picture of your data.

But here's an approach.

---

The example of excel content I used(only one sheet).

[image]

I didn't use argument: `sheet_name=None`(if it only contains one sheet)

```
cells = pd.read_excel('example.xlsx',header=None, index_col=None, usecols="B", skiprows=5)
cells = cells.rename(columns={1:"B"}) # rename column for readability
print(cells)
```

Output

```
    B
0   1
1   4
2   2
3  10
4   1
5   4
6   3
```

It looks like you wanna put a series into list,

therefore we select the series, and its column name is 'B'

```
cells['B'].values.tolist()
```

Output

```
[1, 4, 2, 10, 1, 4, 3]
```

---

#### With multi-sheets

And we try to put every B4 of each sheet into a list.

sheet1
[image]
B4=19

sheet2
[image]
B4=11

sheet3
[image]
B4=20

```
sheets = pd.read_excel('example_3sheets.xlsx',sheet_name=None,header=None, index_col=None, usecols="B", skiprows=3)
print(sheets)
```

Output

```
{'sheet1':     1
0  19
1  12
2  15, 'sheet2':     1
0  11
1  17
2  13, 'sheet3':     1
0  20
1  15
2  15}
```

That is actually three key-value pairs,
like three boxes with name on it,
and what is in the box?
a `DataFrame`!
That's why you got the error syntax, while the dict's values are not `list`-like content.

You can select the first `dataframe` by:

```
sheets['sheet1']
```

Output

```
    1
0  19
1  12
2  15
```

And check the type:

```
type(sheets['sheet1'])
```

Output

```
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

Iterate for every `dataframe`

```
for key in sheets:
    print(sheets[key])
```

Output

```
    1
0  19
1  12
2  15
    1
0  11
1  17
2  13
    1
0  20
1  15
2  15
```

---

#### Finally

According to the `skiprows=3`, `B4` is in every `dataframe`'s first element, we can select by `iloc`

```
b4_in_every_sheet = []
for key in sheets:
    b4_in_every_sheet.append(sheets[key].iloc[0,0])

print(b4_in_every_sheet)
```

Output

```
[19, 11, 20]
```

another way with **list comprehension**

```
b4_in_every_sheet_2 = [sheets[key].iloc[0,0] for key in sheets]
print(b4_in_every_sheet_2)
```

Output

```
[19, 11, 20]
```

Hope it helps.